# How to know UART DMA TX is finished for RS485 enable process in STM32F4 CubeMX

Tags: uart, stm32, stm32f4, rs485, hal-library

I am using STM32F4 series MCU with STM32CubeMX enviroment. I can send and receive data without problem in RS232 physical layer.

My problem is that when I use with it in RS-485 physical layer, I should know when transmission process is finished, last bit is sent from shift register and I am ready to terminate transmit function and enable receive function of RS-485 chip.

What is the flag convention of UART_Busy_Flag or related flag with this process.

Comment: You need to look for the Transmission Complete (TC) bit and the Transmission Complete Interrupt Enable bit (TCIE).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the following function:

```
HAL_StatusTypeDef HAL_UART_Transmit_DMA(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart, uint8_t *pData, uint16_t Size)
```

and make sure that the UART and the DMA interrupts are enabled.

If you look into the implementation, (only a part of it):

```
/* Set the UART DMA transfer complete callback */
huart->hdmatx->XferCpltCallback = UART_DMATransmitCplt;

/* Set the UART DMA Half transfer complete callback */
huart->hdmatx->XferHalfCpltCallback = UART_DMATxHalfCplt;

/* Set the DMA error callback */
huart->hdmatx->XferErrorCallback = UART_DMAError;

/* Enable the UART transmit DMA Stream */
tmp = (uint32_t*)&pData;
HAL_DMA_Start_IT(huart->hdmatx, *(uint32_t*)tmp, (uint32_t)&huart->Instance->DR, Size);
```

The DMA will be started in IT mode, and there are three `HAL_UART` callbacks which will be called by the callback functions above.

1. Transmit complete callback: `HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback`
2. Half of the bytes are sent: `HAL_UART_TxHalfCpltCallback`
3. Error: `HAL_UART_ErrorCallback`

All of these have weak declaration so you have to implement them. For example:

```
void HAL_UART_TxCpltCallback(UART_HandleTypeDef *huart)
{
    if (huart->Instance == USART1)  // change USART instance
    {
       // Transmit complete handle RS-485 related stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: But in the Normal mode I get some problem with using, this is usefull in circular mode